# SOAP client handlers occasionally not called

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, websphere

I am having a SOAP client handler that intercepts the message and writes the wsse security token in the header. However for some reason the handler does not intercept the SOAP message on certain occasions resulting in the header not containing the wsse security token and hence the request failing.

Can anybody please point out as to what could be the cause for me to experience this scenario on certain occasions only.

Some additional info. I am experiencing this only after migrating our application from WAS6.1 with Portal V6.1 to WAS 7 with Portal 7.

Regards
Snehan Solomon

Answer (score 0):

I expect an error is being thown, and you're not seeing everything because you're only catching an exception. Try wrapping the offending code in a try/catch for throwable.